# Custom WPF control does not exist in Design Mode when implemented in .cs file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

The VisualStudio 2015 project I'm working on uses a .cs file to create a custom control derived from System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using BAB_HMI.Views;

namespace BAB_HMI.Controls
{
    public class HMIViewRadioButton : RadioButton
    {
        public HMIView ViewType
        {
            get { return (HMIView)GetValue(ViewTypeProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ViewTypeProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty ViewTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ViewType", typeof(HMIView), typeof(HMIViewRadioButton));
    }
}
```

The resource dictionary references the control like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:BAB_HMI.Controls">

    <Style x:Key="ModuleRadioButton" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:HMIViewRadioButton}">
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

There are no compile errors but when opening App.xaml I get an error saying "An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary".

The error goes away if I use a .xaml file to create the custom control and put the HMIViewRadioButton code in the code-behind .xaml.cs file, but I don't want to do this because the error is only displaying on my machine. Other people on the team are not getting this error.

Is there a local setting that enables design mode to see custom controls that are implemented in .cs files instead of .xaml.cs files? ...or is it something else that's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. I had the "Platform target" build setting set to "x64". Changing it to "Any CPU" fixed the problem. I think this may be because Visual Studio is running as "x86" in Design Mode and it can't use assemblies built with just "x64" set.